# Where can I find the statistics of import crude oil to China?

Tags: data-request, china

Is there any website that shows statistics of import crude oil and commodities to China daily or monthly?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how helpful this is but the way the information is displayed is really nice. https://oec.world/en/profile/country/chn/

Comment: Beauty is in the eye of the beholder, but these are objectively yearly statistics.

Answer (score 0):

There are many statistics here: https://fred.stlouisfed.org/tags/series?t=china%3Bimports

The UN has an excelent website with monthly trade flows: https://comtrade.un.org/monthly/Public/ReleaseInfo.aspx